# How do you handle breadcrumbs with lazyloaded components using react router?

Tags: javascript, react-router

I have been looking for an example on how to handle breadcrumbs for routes that are lazy loaded.  I have been able to get this to work correctly on the server, but haven't been able to get the lazy loaded component which is masked by getComponent() on the client. How do I get access to the async components?

*routes.js*

```
module.exports = {
    component: Layout,
    childRoutes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: App,
            childRoutes: [
                {
                    path: '/lazy',
                    component: Lazy, // Lazy loaded component
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

*Lazy.js*

```
// Server polyfill
if (typeof require.ensure !== 'function') { require.ensure = function(d, c) { c(require) }; }

module.exports = {
    path: 'detail',
    getComponent: function(location, cb) {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
            cb(null, require('./components/Detail')); //Component I want to access
        });
    }
};
```

*Breadcrumbs.js*

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Breadcrumbs extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        routes: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    render() {
        const { routes } = this.props;
        return (
            <ol className="breadcrumbs">
                {routes.map((route, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={index}>{route.component.title}</li>
                    );
                })}
            </ol>
        );
    }
}

export default Breadcrumbs;
```

The problem is the async route looks like:

```
{
    path: 'detail',
    component: {
        getComponent: function()
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
    path: 'detail',
    component: {
        title: 'Lazy Detail'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you have, I'd just put the `title` on the route object rather than the component - that should resolve your issues there and give you a bit more flexibility.

If you have to do this, you can use a custom `RoutingContext`, but this is a semi-private API that will potentially go away in v1.1.x. In general it'd seem cleaner to define this on the `<Route>`, though.

Comment: hmm... I was hoping I could avoid putting route meta outside of the lazy loaded component.

Comment: Then you could use `<RoutingContext>` to drop the `components` on context. Be aware that this API will change, though.